# Conditional Alert in SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to create an Alert which should only fire when certain field value is blank or something like that ? I don't find any reference for the same anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

If your alert criteria can be expressed in a view, you can then do this through the UI without code.  Create the view on the list with your criteria.  Then set an alert for the list.  In the section for set alerts for these changes, select the someone changes an item that appears in this view and select your view from the dropdown list.

This option is not easily discovered in 2010 as the option only appears after a custom view exists for the list (except for the task list, which has a number of views included by default).

[image: alert settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow through SharePoint designer to achieve this functionality.

Comment: You're going to give more detail, aren't you?

Comment: Madhur, I believe so..but if already some workflows are running then it will make things more complex.. But what If user wants to subscribe an alert by own rather than something running behind the scene ?

Comment: @Rishi: Can you explain more about this complexity? How about a workflow which can be manually started, in that case the action item on part of user is just starting the workflow rather than subscribing the oob alert. In that case you can name the workflow as "Subscribe Alert workflow"